# Count spaces within exploded quotations

Tags: php, regex, arrays, count

In simplest terms im trying to change the data string if more than 4 spaces are found within quotations. I'm able to do this on a simple string but not within exploded quotes as it becomes an array which count functions wont accept. Is there a regex to do what im looking for in this case or something?

```
$data = 'Hello World "This is a test string! Jack and Jill went up the hill."';
$halt = 'String had more than 4 spaces.';
$arr = explode('"', $data);
if (substr_count($arr, ' ') >= 4) {
$data = implode('"', $arr);
$data = $halt;
```

Comment: `substr_count` cannot be applied to array.

Comment: The question is unclear... Do you need to see if there are 4 spaces in any individual substring wrapped in `"` characters? More that 4 spaces total in all substrings wrapped in `"` characters? What about substrings wrapped in `'`?

Comment: Also note that in all 3 cases, `explode()` isn't going to help you... it splits the string on the specified delimiter, when what you really want is each substring **enclosed in** the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your request, this will do the job

```
$data = 'Hello World "This is a test string! Jack and Jill went up the hill."';
$halt = 'String had more than 4 spaces.';

// split $data on " and captures them
$arr = preg_split('/(")/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

// must we count spaces ?
$countspace = 0;
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    // swap $countspace when " is encountered
    if ($str == '"') $countspace = !$countspace;
    // we have to count spaces
    if ($countspace) {
        // more than 4 spaces
        if (substr_count($str, ' ') >= 4) {
            // change data 
            $data = $halt;
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $data,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
String had more than 4 spaces.
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, except the whole string should be replaced not just whats in quotes. I tried changing it myself but didnt get the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you define:

```
function count_spaces($str) {return substr_count($str, ' '); }
```

you can then use `array_sum(array_map("count_spaces", $arr))` to count all of the spaces in all of the strings in `$arr`.

Comment: Except that `$arr` in the original question is just a string split on `"`, so the count is the same as just doing `substr_count($data, '  ')`. There are much deeper problems here than not being able to sum across the elements of an array...